# Increase in Solubility of a Gas with an Increase in Temperature

Tags: temperature, physical-chemistry

On the [UC Davis ChemWiki](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Solubilty/Temperature_Effects_on_the_Solubility_of_Gases) I read, "some gases have an increase in solubility with an increase in temperature."

I understand why this is applicable to solids in liquids such as water, but why is it applicable as well as for gases in liquids?

Comment: Can you cite where did you read this?

Comment: Here is the link: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Equilibria/Solubilty/Temperature_Effects_on_the_Solubility_of_Gases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dissolution of the gas *absorbs* heat in order to occur (e.g. $N_2$ gas dissolving in benzene):
$$Undissolved\ N_2 + Heat \rightleftharpoons Dissolved\ N_2$$

then raising the temperature will add more heat and by [Le Chatelier's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle) force the reaction to the right. In other words, if the dissolution requires heat to occur and you add more heat, more dissolution will occur. This corresponds to an increase in solubility with an increase in temperature.

If the dissolution of the gas *produces* heat when it occurs (e.g. $O_2$ gas dissolving in water):

$$Undissolved\ O_2 \rightleftharpoons Dissolved\ O_2 + Heat$$

as raising the temperature adds more heat, having the extra heat around will instead allow more gas to *leave* the dissolved state. This corresponds to a decrease in solubility with a decrease in temperature.

The model that is used to explain whether the gas absorbs or produces heat upon dissolving in a liquid solvent is based on [the bonding of the liquid molecules with each other vs. with the gas molecules](http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/solutions/faq/temperature-gas-solubility.shtml).

Comment: I do not understand why raising the temperature prevents some dissolution.

Comment: If instead of the equation I wrote above (for when the gas absorbs heat to dissolve) the equation is "Dissolved Gas + Heat --> Undissolved Gas", then having extra heat around will allow more gas to go undissolved